How can I charge a 2023 14-inch MacBook Pro from dock USB-C cable without using the attached monitor?
Context:

I have a 2023 14-inch MacBook Pro running Sonoma 14.4
I have a desk dock monitor with speakers, microphone, keyboard, and mouse
I connect the MacBook to the dock via USB-C; This is also the cable I use to charge the laptop

Problem:

This dock accepts several inputs, and indeed my Linux machine is multiplexed with it. I switch the inputs as needed throughout the day.
The MacBook seems to have no way to disable the second monitor when I am using Linux and just using the USB-C to charge the MacBook
Most unhelpfully, the MacBook sends critical content (e.g. the text box to log in) to the second monitor (where it is not shown).

The dock has only one main USB-C cable. It is impractical to swap it out, so using a power-only USB-C cable is not a reasonable solution.
I am willing to do unusual things, as SIP is already disabled and I've had to run a self-signed root volume to work around some other issues. I’m hoping a file modification or a shell command could make MacOS forget (and then later remember) that a monitor exists when detected on a thunderbolt bus and connected via a hub.
On Linux, I can turn off the external display without unplugging the cables. How do I do this on MacOs 14.4?

If you want your display to charge your Mac but prevent it from being configured as an additional display, you will have to use a power-only USB-C cable, that is, a cable that doesn't transfer data. For example, the USB-C cable I got with my Intel MacBook Pro is such a cable, and you can find similar cables online.

I find that quite hard to believe, as it is a pretty normal software feature to be able to disable an attached monitor. I am willing to do strange things, including patching or modifying the operating system. I've already had to disable SIP and run a self-signed root volume to work around some other limitations.

Excellent clarification MRule - most people really don’t want to contemplate how the sealed system volume works. Totally fine to ask for that low level modification here especially when it’s clear. I did a minor edit, since USB-C is the connector and not the over-the-wire protocol that needs altering. Do you know if your hub is USB 4 or which version of thunderbolt/USB? (System profiler or information will report this)

Hi bmike, thanks for your engagement. It sounds like (unless someone has hacked together some magic sudo lines already), the question may be unanswerable. I'm not sure what the dock is using, it's a Dell monitor that also has a mic, camera, and attached keyboard and mouse. When I plug it in, USB hubs for the following versions appear: 3.2 3.0 3.1 2.1. At least one of these is probably the hub in the apple keyboard (old version with the wire). Nothing 4.0. I guess the trick might be to see if disabling a node in this tree of hubs also masks the monitors?

I can't vote to close my own question, can I?
